# XSLT Subtraction Operator

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

Just Like | operator, can we use the - operator on a node-set?

I have a two set of nodes - Set1 and Set2. I want to get another set which has all the elements in Set1 which are not in Set2.

Then I want to iterate over that set like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Set1 - $Set2">
    <!--Process Child Nodes-->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Well, http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers defines `-` for numbers, not for node-sets. In XPath 2.0 you have `except`: `$nodeseq1 except $nodeseq2`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @Madeyedexter Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Comment: The C# CompiledTransform class. I am also free to use msxsl extension.

Comment: EXSLT offers a `set:intersection()` extension function - unfortunately it's not supported by MS. Use the method proposed by Martin Honnen (also known as the Kayesian method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath 1.0 you can use `$set1[count(.|$set2) != count($set2)]`.

Comment: This is a clever answer. Thanks a lot. I could have arrived at this if I hadn't  been looking for a set-subtraction operator.